# how compile SynEdit in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, compilation, compiler-errors, synedit

I tried to load and use 'SynEdit_D7.dpk' and 'SynEdit_R7.dpk' in Delphi 7 to install but following error raised:

```
[Fatal Error] SynEditHighlighter.pas(57): File not found: 'SynEditHighlighterOptions.dcu'
```

I did:

1. downloaded [SynEdit-2_0_8.zip](http://cznic.dl.sourceforge.net/project/synedit/1%20-%20Stable%20Releases/SynEdit-2_0_8.zip)
2. Extracted somewhere and opened Delphi 7.
3. Loaded SynEdit_D7.dpk.
4. Clicked on install.
5. Received error.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please describe exactly what steps you took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should add source files path to [Delphi library path](https://www.anonimg.com/img/8a4e0c46071087ebe12d6bc4eeaf4f69.png) (Tools | Environment options) and then build without problems!
I built `SynEdit_D7.dpk` without `SynEdit_R7.dpk`.

Problem Solved.

> I don't have sufficient points to add image! added link.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. (StackOverflow is not a discussion forum.)

Comment: But this is Solution!

Answer (score 1):

It seems (based on your steps) that you are trying to install the design-time package before the run-time package has been built. You must first build the run-time package `SynEdit_R7.dpk` and then continue to installing the design-time package `SynEdit_D7.dpk`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Delphi 2007 and I am very sure that this is a bug in SynEdit. They most likely forgot to add "SynEditHighlighterOptions.pas" to the DPKs of the earlier Delphi versions. Separately adding it to the runtime package solves the problem. No need to change the search path just for 1 unit.

If you have a SourceForge account, I would be glad if you could create a bug report for it.